# Proof Verification: If $|x-x_0|<min(\frac{ε}{2(|y_0|+1)}, 1), |y-y_0|<\frac{ε}{2(|x_0|+1)}$ then $|xy-x_0y_0|<ε$ - Spivak's Calculus Problem 1-21

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, inequality

This is problem 21 from Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 1.

> Prove that if $$|x-x_0|<\min(\frac{ε}{2(|y_0|+1)}, 1), |y-y_0|<\frac{ε}{2(|x_0|+1)}$$ then $|xy-x_0y_0|<ε$

This is my proof:

$|x|-|x_0|\leq|x-x_0|<1 \Rightarrow |x|<1+|x_0| \Rightarrow \frac{ε}{2(|x_0|+1)}<\frac{ε}{2|x|}$

$\therefore |y-y_0|<\frac{ε}{2|x|} \Rightarrow |xy-xy_0|<\frac{ε}{2}$

$|x-x_0|<\frac{ε}{2(|y_0|+1)} \Rightarrow |x-x_0|\cdot(|y_0|+1)<\frac{ε}{2} \Rightarrow |xy_0-x_0y_0|+ |x-x_0|<\frac{ε}{2}$

However, since $|x-x_0|\geq 0, |xy_0-x_0y_0|\leq |xy_0-x_0y_0|+|x+x_0|\Rightarrow |xy_0-x_0y_0|<\frac{ε}{2}$

Adding the two inequalities together I obtain, $|xy-xy_0|+|xy_0-x_0y_0|<ε$

Lastly, from the triangle inequality I obtain, $|xy-xy_0+xy_0-x_0y_0|=|xy-x_0y_0|<ε$, which completes the proof.

I'm posting this proof as it is quite different to the one Spivak gives. Is it correct?

Comment: Looks OK to me, except for the step $|x-x_0|<\frac{ε}{2(|y_0|+1)} \Rightarrow |xy_0-x_0y_0|+ |x-x_0|<\frac{ε}{2}$. Could you elaborate and explain a few more intermediary steps on this one ?

Comment: Just edited that, thanks for the tip! :-)

Comment: An alternative approach, assuming you are talking about real numbers, is just to create lots of cases, doubling for each $|\cdot|$ and $\min$ to turn the entire thing into several algebra problems.  But that approach does not  generalize to complex numbers.

Comment: I don't think Spivak intends anything to be generalized to complex numbers as these are introduced near the end of the book, so yeah I am talking about real numbers. Thanks for your approach!

Comment: By the way, there's a typo in your line starting with "However, since :" : the $|x+x_0|$ in the equation should be $|x-x_0|$